# Unique solution for a given BVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

> Consider the BVP:$$\frac{dy}{dt}=f(t,y)~,~y(0)=y_{0},$$
>   where $f(t,y)$ is a bounded function, continuous on the set $\Omega(t,y)=\{ |t| < a , |y-y_{0}| < b   \}$ and satisfies a Lipschitz condition there with Lipschitz constant $K.$

**Question.** Find a condition which will ensure that a unique solution will exist inside $\Omega$ and that the condition has a maximal area on $\Omega.$

The solution of the IVP is given by
$$y(t)=y_{0}+\int_{0}^{t} f(s,y(s))~ds.$$
I thought Lipshcitz being satisfy is enough to guarantee the uniqueness of the solution. Also how should I go by  and comment about the area ? Any help in solving this is much appreciated.

Comment: You want to make sure that for all $|t|<a$ you have $|y(t)-y_0|<b$. Use the maximum of $f$ as Lipschitz constant for $y(t)$.

Comment: @LutzL, thanks. Did you mean:
$$|y(t) - y_0| \leq M \cdot |t|, < a \cdot M.$$ 
where $M=\max_{s}|f(s,y(s))|.$

Comment: Yes. Which demands that $a·M\le b$. This is a typical construction in the proof of the localized Picard-Lindelöf theorem.

Comment: @LutzL, I see, I didn't know that. One more question, how can I show that the condition has maximal area in $\Omega$ ?

Comment: What is "maximal area"? And what are the parameters that can be manipulated? The Lipschitz condition can be used to get a linear bound on $f$. Then one can use the Grönwall lemma to get perhaps a less restrictive bound on the growth of $y(t)$.

Comment: Maximal area is the maximal length on which the solution is defined. Could please explain how to get that one. Thank you.

Comment: You can't.  There is no good way to get the true maximal  interval. But I think they mean $|t|\le \min(a,b/M)$.